# How to stop downloading of a streaming video

Tags: windows, firefox, video-streaming

This is a problem I have in my mind for a long time and now I want to ask Super Users.

I often watch streaming videos on various video sharing sites and Facebook. I click on the "Play" button on the relevant online player, and video starts to load and starts to play after a short while. The problem is, if I don't like the video after watching it for a while, there is no way to stop loading (I can only *pause* video which doesn't cancel loading). I have only one chance: to reload the page (reloading is not a good option when browsing videos on a long Facebook page because it results in loss of my *anchor* at the page and takes me to the top of that page). If the video is too long, it exploits all my internet connection and I have to wait for this load process to finish until I can watch another video. I don't want that.

So I'm looking for a solution to force the stream-download to stop whenever I don't want to watch that video. I'm on Windows 7 x64 with Firefox 3.6.10.

**EDIT:** It seems that YouTube has a feature to do this; but not all video broadcasting services have a "Stop download" option. I'm looking for a global solution which is not only valid for YouTube but also for the others.

Comment: One of the few problems with endless scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

You could use flashblock, block the objects you don't want to play, or block them by default, click to play, then re-block to stop.

Answer (score 3):

Mehper C. Palavuzlar, I've got a real easy fix for you. Just click at the very end of the video timeline. This way the video will stop the previous download and download only a few seconds reaming.

This works with any video streaming site that allows the user to jump at any point in the timeline (probably 99% of the sites).

Comment: I tried it on several flash videos but it does not work. No chance even on the most popular ones like YouTube. I can only jump to the end of the loaded part. FYI!

Comment: That's just not true. What browser are you using? Try firefox or Opera. I just did it on both of then in youtube. Try reinstalling you Adobe Flash. This is probably a problem with your system. Try another computer if nothing works, just so you be sure this solution works.

Comment: I tried it on 3 different computers with IE8 and FF 3.6. Your fix only works outside **Facebook**. For example, I **can't jump** to the end of any videos **in Facebook**, but if I open the video **in its original page** (e.g. YouTube page), your fix works. So, this is not feasible for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Youtube, simply right-click the video and click `Stop download`.

Comment: Thanks; but what about the others?

Comment: @Mehper: What do you mean? IIRC, YouTube videos only start loading when you click play, which should give you plenty of time to stop the download if you don't like the video.

Comment: I mean the video services other than YouTube. They don't have a "Stop download" option. My question is not specifically about YouTube. I'm looking for a solution which can be applied comprehensively.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Aardvark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4111/) extension for Firefox, you can simply erase the player object from the page, which will stop it from playing. Undoing the erase will start it playing again.
There are other extensions, for Firefox and for other browsers, that can do the same.

Other extensions can also block/unblock streaming, like Adblock, NoScript etc.

Answer (score 0):

On facebook ( as you pointed ) , you can click on `CROSS` at right top of the video window, it stops downloading the video.

Comment: I can't see any cross on any Facebook video. There is only the "Remove" button at right top of the video which completely removes it. Can you post a screenshot?